# Onesignal not finding upgrade reciever class in apk

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, onesignal

So I am building an Android App using Unity 5.6.1 and Onesignal(Latest SDk from the site), and when i build the apk it crashes. Looking at the logcat i see this message

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.onesignal.UpgradeReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/asec/com.MyPad3D.MazeWalkVR-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/asec/com.MyPad3D.MazeWalkVR-2/lib/arm, /mnt/asec/com.MyPad3D.MazeWalkVR-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

I cannot understand what to do now and how to debug this further, any help will be appreciated !

Comment: Are you defined this class in Android  manifest file?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @Rims no, in the documentation it does not say so to do anything in the manifest

Comment: @Hristo C# script in Unity

Comment: Could you post all related code that you modified or added. Also please take a look at [this](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/java-lang-classnotfoundexception.106258/) thread, since there is a similar problem.

Comment: @Hristo Thanks for your reply, this is a project i joined in just now and it is already published on iOS and my task is to convert to Android, There is alot of scripts and scenes to post here, none of it seems relevant to the onesignal plugin

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add this line in Manifest file in Android.In one of the App I also implemented this One signal.

```
<receiver android:name="com.onesignal.UpgradeReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Apart of that you should also Add this lines in Android Manifest file.

```
   <meta-data
                android:name="onesignal_app_id"
                android:value="yyyyssyshsbchdsdavbavbfjvbkfdj" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="onesignal_google_project_number"
                android:value="xxxxxxxxx" />

            <receiver
                android:name="com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                    <category android:name="com.newsreader.sitl" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
            <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpenedReceiver" />

            <service android:name="com.onesignal.GcmIntentService" />
            <service
                android:name="com.onesignal.SyncService"
                android:stopWithTask="false" />

            <activity
                android:name="com.onesignal.PermissionsActivity"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

            <service android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationRestoreService" />

            <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.BootUpReceiver">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver

>
   <service
            android:name="com.newsreader.notificationHelper.NotificationExtender"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationExtender" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <meta-data android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT" android:value="DISABLE" />
```

Comment: <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
the MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED thing, does it need to be replaced by my game's package name ?

Comment: No no..no need to replace.Have u added Onesignal in build.gradle  
 compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar' in android.

Comment: Hi @Rims, sorry for the late reply, no i have not. Im not sure what that even is? Where do i find it ?

Comment: this is not mentioned in the docs, are you sure it is mandatory?
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs